# adding more items to custom ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, custom-adapter

I have a listview which i  populate using cusome ArrayAdapter , each row in the listview contain image and title .

i followed this tutorial http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html 
to create custom arrayadapter and populate my listview using it like the following :

here i attach the adapter to my list in MainActivity:

```
newsAdapter = new NewsAdapter( getActivity() , titles , images );
listView.setAdapter(newsAdapter);
```

each of images and titles are ArrayList objects which i want to populate my listview with.

here is my ArrayAdapter :

```
public class NewsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private final Context context;
private final ArrayList<String> titles;
private final ArrayList<String> images;

public NewsAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<String> titles, ArrayList<String> images ) {
    super(context, R.layout.drawer_list_item, titles);
    this.context = context;
    this.titles = titles;
    this.images = images;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_list_item, parent, false);
    TextView title = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.news_title);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.news_thumble);
    title.setText(titles.get(position));
    new DownloadImageTask(imageView).execute(images.get(position));
    return rowView;
}



 }
```

this code works perfectly and the listView populated with the data (images and titles).

**The Question:**

Is it possible to append the Listview (Add more rows) in this implementation ? (e.g using newsAdapter.add() method) .

and if this is possible , how to achieve that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yeah, you could for example implement an `addItem(String title, String image)` method in your custom adapter.
this method then adds the passed values to your `titles` and `images` list.

after changing the content of the listadapter you have to invalidate the view by calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` in that adapter to redraw the listview.

call this method then in your main activity to add more items to the list. (eg `newsAdapter.addItem("some Title", imageString);`

Comment: I followed your instruction but it does not work. Did google change it in a newer version?

Comment: afaik this method is still valid and a good way for list views. but nowadays the recyclerview is - depending on the specific needs - in some cases a good replacement for listviews.