# updating list view in android studio

Tags: android, listview, notifydatasetchanged

I am creating an app in android studio.

I need to update the *list view* with a new url that is sent via text message.

How do I add the new *url* to my list?

This is what I currently have for my main code.

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 ListView list;
WebView webView;
ArrayList<String> sites = new ArrayList<> ("https://www.google.com", "https://www.yahoo.com", "https://www.apple.com");
String [] url = {"https://www.google.com", "https://www.yahoo.com", "https://www.apple.com"};

MyBroadcastReceiver receiver;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
    MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter(this, sites);
    sites.add("new site");
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setDividerHeight(5);
    webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){});

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),sites[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");
            webView.loadUrl(url[position]);

        }
    });

    receiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
    registerReceiver(receiver,filter);
}


}
```

MyListAdapter:

```
public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private Activity context_;
private ArrayList<String> sites;

//constructor
public MyListAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<String> sites){
    super(context,R.layout.row,sites);
    context_ = context;
    this.sites = sites;
}

public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    if(convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = context_.getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row,null);
    }

    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    if(holder == null){
        holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        holder.tv_link.setText(sites.get(position));
    }
    else{
        holder.tv_link.setText(sites.get(position));
    }
    return convertView;
}

private class ViewHolder{
    TextView tv_link;
    public ViewHolder(View row){
        tv_link = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_link);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You should post the code for your MyListAdapter class, but basically what you need to do is add a method to your adapter that inserts a new element to its sites list, and then use notifyDataSetChanged on it to update the views.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [adding more items to custom ArrayAdapter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21831437/adding-more-items-to-custom-arrayadapter)

Comment: I have added the code, do I need to edit anything in that? if so how do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

you defined ***sites*** as final also you cant update it , instead of String[]  use a arraylist of String :

```
  ArrayList<String> sites = new ArrayList<>();
```

change constructor of adapter to accept a ArrayList instead of array and when new data received use this :

```
sites.add("new site !");
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

in constructor of Adapter if you do like this:

```
  public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<String> array;

    public MyListAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<String> mArray) {
        super(ctx, 0, mArray);
        this.context = ctx;
        this.array = mArray; 
    }

    //other methods
}
```

**adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();** can update dataset and listView  updated !

but if you do like below :

```
 public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<String> array;

    public MyListAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<String> mArray) {
        super(ctx, 0, mArray);
        this.context = ctx;
        for (int i = 0; i < mArray.size(); i++) // copy global ArrayList
            this.array.add(mArray.get(i));
    }

    //other methods
}
```

first , you must create a method to update localDataset Of Adapter then call  `this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

like below :

```
 public void newDataReceived(ArrayList<String> newArr){
            this.array.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < newArr.size(); i++)
                this.array.add(newArr.get(i));

            this.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

and call adapter method when new data received !

```
 sites.add("new site ");
    adapter.newDataReceived(sites);
```

Codes are manually typed and  may have the wrong syntax , i hope it can help you

Comment: it says cannot infer arguments, unable to resolve constructer in this line :  ArrayList<String> sites = new ArrayList<>("https://www.google.com", "https://www.yahoo.com", "https://www.apple.com");

Comment: @S.Hobbs take out all those semicolons but the last one

Comment: There actually isn't semicolons in my app, I'm not sure as to why they are there.

Comment: @drawinfinity  also I have added my adapter list to my questions above because I am unsure how to edit mine to what you have written. can you explain?

Comment: you must either enter addresses one by one in onCreate : sites.add("https://www.google.com");
 Or like this : 
sites = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("https://www.google.com", "https://www.yahoo.com", "https://www.apple.com"));

Comment: private ArrayList<String> sites = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("google.com", "yahoo.com", "apple.com"));

because of semicolon in previous comment i type Arraylist again

Comment: in the above coding answer where is talks about newDataReceived, where does the sites.add("new site ");
    adapter.newDataReceived(sites);  belong? which java class? Mybroadcastreceiver, main or listadapater ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using ArrayList and then add when you need to add new urls in that arrayList. Then call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

don't use final if you know you may need to update the value